# How to use a range variable across two subs?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering how I can pass a variable defined as a range between subs. I am trying to evaluate 4 different cases (for simplicity, only two cases are shown) where all the cases use the same sub to find two values from a table. I originally had the `rng` and `e` variables defined in the `getR()` sub, and it had no issues. However, now that I've split it up, I get a 'object required 424' error on the `set e=....` line of the `getR()` sub.

I looked some things up online and found that I should be able to declare a public variable, as `Public e as Workbook` for example. Would I need to do this for all of my variables that are passed between subs? Is there a better way to do this? Please let me know.

This first sub takes the speed inputted on a sheet, and then checks which case it should use. Once it finds the case, I want it to pass the `rng` and `e` variables to the next sub.

```
Sub selectSpeed()

  Dim Speed As Integer 'define speed
  Speed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("d3")

  Dim lanes As Integer 'define number of lanes
  lanes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("d7")

  Dim a As String      'define the road A value
  a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("d6")
  
  Dim rng As Range, e As Range

Select Case Speed
  
  Case Is = 40      'if speed is 40, use this range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table").Range("b16:b31")
    Set e = rng
    Call getR
    
  Case Is = 50      'if speed is 50, use alternate range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table").Range("c16:c31")
    Set e = rng
    Call getR

End Select

End Sub
```

Next, I want this sub below to be called and use the `rng`, `e`, `a`, `lanes` variables defined above, to complete the loop and take values from a table.

```
Sub getR()

  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 10
    Set e = rng.Find(what:=a)
      If Not e Is Nothing Then
      r = e.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If lanes = 2 Then
          a = e.Offset(0, 1).Value
          Exit For
        Else
          a = e.Offset(0, 2).Value
          Exit For
        End If
      Else
      a = a + 0.001
      End If
  Next i

Range("H3").Value = a
Range("H4").Value = r
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Sub to use arguments/variables...

```
Sub getR(rng as Range, e As Range, a As Range, lanes As Range)
```

And then instead of `Call getR`, supply the arguments (there is no need to use the word `Call` to call it.

```
getR rng, e, a, lanes
```

Not sure if it will do what you expect it to do tho, but your question was about how to pass ranges as variables, not how to get your code to do something specific.

Note that in your routine, you are setting `a` equal to a value, not a range, which is why I am not sure it's going to do what you expect it to do. You may get other unrelated errors. To troubleshoot this, make a really simple example that demonstrates how to pass a range and then expand on that once you understand how it works.

```
Sub Test()
  getR Range("A1")
End Sub

Sub getR(range1 As Range)
  MsgBox range1.Address
End Sub
```